# apt-offline on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, debian, python, cmd.exe

Following [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) tutorial, I don't know how to reproduce step 2 on a windows machine:

```
apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --threads 5
```

How do I install `apt-offline` on a Windows machine so I can run this command?

This is what I have tried:
I installed Python 2.7.5 on Windows and downloaded the apt-offline package.
Then I ran the setup.py script contained in the folder.
First with the build parameter and then with the install parameter as described in the INSTALL document.

The only way I can get apt-offline to work is with:

```
cd C:\apt-offline-1.3
python apt-offline
```

It never works by entering apt-offline or python apt-offline into cmd.

Comment: Tell us what you've done. Have you successfully installed `apt-offline` on Windows?

Comment: How did you get to download `apt-offline` on windows? I can't find any download link anywhere.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/771044/how-to-make-apt-offline-on-windows/1833434#1833434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a feature! Windows, just like *nix has a [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), a list of directories in which it will search for executable files when a program's name is given in the command line. If a given executable is not in one of those directories, you will need to use its [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) (not to be confused with `$PATH`) to run it.

So, you have a few choices:

- You can add the directory in which you have saved `apt-offline` to your `$PATH` ([source](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)):

  1. From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
  2. Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
  3. In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
- You can use the complete path to run the program:

  ```
  python C:\apt-offline-1.3\apt-offline
  ```
- You can change directories to `C:\apt-offline-1.3\` and run it from there which is exactly what you've been doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why do I have to run through the installation process at all as mentioned on the [apt-offline GitHub page](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/blob/master/INSTALL).
Shouldn't this take care of integrating the command `apt-offline` into Windows?

Comment: @codingaround apparently not. Since most things don't happen from the command line in Windows, adding a program to the PATH might not always happen. For example, windows shortcuts use absolute paths not just the program's name. The installation probably just links the program to the necessary libraries, places files in the correct folders etc.

Comment: The setup.py installed apt-offline into the site-packages folder of Python 2.7.5. Is this what you mean by "places files in the correct folders etc."? So, is there no reason to run the setup.py at all?

Comment: @codingaround I don't know, I'd have to read the source. Does it perhaps compile something? Collect information about your system? Set up environment variables?

Comment: The [setup.py](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/blob/master/setup.py) script does not seem to take care of commands at all. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14002061/2569639) answer on StackOverflow explains it, I think. While the setup script does not contain `entry_point`, because it's not supported in distutils, there is a line called `scripts=['apt-offline', 'apt-offline-gui']`

Comment: I tried out all 3 of your suggested methods and 2 of them didn't work. Here is what happens if I use the first method: I added the folder containing apt-offline to `$PATH`, restarted cmd and ran apt-offline without success. Method 2 does only work this way: `python C:\apt-offline-1.3\apt-offline`.

Comment: @codingaround yes, sorry, that was a typo because I copy pasted, the second command was supposed to be like that. As for adding the directory to the path, I can't help you if you don't tell me the exact error message. "It did not work" is not very clear. Actually, I probably can't help you anyway since I don't really use Windows. Did you finally get it to work? Oh, and the `setup.py` looks more like a configuration file than an installer.

Comment: C:\apt-offline-1.3 was added to %PATH%. After this I typed `apt-offline` into cmd, which resulted in: `The command "apt-offline" is either mistyped or does not exist.` Typing `python apt-offline` into cmd results in: `python: can't open file 'apt-offline': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`