# How to make apt-offline on windows

Tags: debian, python, make

[Apt-offline](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline) claims to be a utility that allows you to install packages on Debian without internet connection. It can be [downloaded](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/archive/master.zip) from the git repository.
As with many free software, the problem is that it's undocumented and that you have build it yourself. In the git repository I've linked to, there's a information file `INSTALL`:

```
# Execute the file using the python interpreter
# Assuming python.exe is in your path

# To build
C:\> python setup.py build

# To install
C:\> python setup.py install
```

I've ran build and then install. I could've seen some parse errors spit out by Python. I hope these don't matter. Anyway, I just ended up with a few more folders and few more files without extension (why do some people omit extensions all the time?).

So my question here is just how to build and install the utility properly - given it's possible. (and [this question](https://superuser.com/q/643528/194976) suggests it might be possible)

Comment: Why do you think this would be useful on Windows?  what are you doing?  `why do some people omit extensions all the time?` - Because they are not required or needed on Linux.

Comment: Neither they are required on windows. But it's nice to know what kind of a file it is before opening it. Why shouldn't I be building an application that claims to run under windows?

Comment: ok, so you think you installed it. is one of the files named `apt-offline` or `apt-offline-gui`? if everything is working, you should be able to cd into that directory, and execute either with `python apt-offline-gui`. or you can copy it to your path as your linked thread suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I've just installed it on a Windows XP machine as follows:-

Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.7/).  Make sure you choose the correct architecture (32/64 bit).  Select the option to add `python.exe` to your path as it will make things easier later.

Install [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download). Again, make sure you choose the correct architecture for your Windows.

Download [apt-offline](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/archive/master.zip).  Extract it to the C:\ drive.  The folder will be called `apt-offline-master` - rename it to `apt-offline` to save on your typing later.

Open the Windows terminal. Type the following:-

```
 cd c:\apt-offline
 python setup.py build
 python setup.py install
 python apt-offline-gui
```

Comment: This is an outdated answer, see update.

Answer (score 1):

**Update as of 2024.**
I am working under Portable Msys2, but I guess that makes no difference.
The current version of `apt-offline` seems to depend on PyQt5, not PyQt4.
So using python 3.8, I built and installed with (partial?) success, see output below.
Then, command line `apt-offline` seems to work, but not gui. It might well be a problem with my system, not with the installer:

```
$ python3 apt-offline
usage: apt-offline [-h] [--verbose] [--quiet] [-v] {set,get,install} ...

Offline APT Package Manager - 1.8.5

positional arguments:
  {set,get,install}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --verbose          Enable verbose messages
  --quiet            Enable quiet mode
  -v, --version      show program's version number and exit

(C) 2005 - 2022 Ritesh Raj Sarraf - This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under the GNU GPL
Version 3 (or later) License

$ python3 apt-offline-gui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apt-offline-gui", line 27, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt5' (/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677483/2707864) or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/s1zjen/import_error_all_of_a_sudden/) may hint at the causes of the error, but I didn't try any further.

**Related**:

1. [apt-offline on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/643528/apt-offline-on-windows)

---

Output of the build/install

```
$ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
file apt_offline_gui/resources_rc.py (for module apt_offline_gui.resources_rc) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtMain.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtMain) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip) not found
file apt_offline_gui/resources_rc.py (for module apt_offline_gui.resources_rc) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtMain.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtMain) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip) not found
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-3.8
copying and adjusting apt-offline -> build/scripts-3.8
copying and adjusting apt-offline-gui -> build/scripts-3.8
copying apt-offline-gui-pkexec -> build/scripts-3.8

$ python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
file apt_offline_gui/resources_rc.py (for module apt_offline_gui.resources_rc) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtMain.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtMain) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip) not found
file apt_offline_gui/resources_rc.py (for module apt_offline_gui.resources_rc) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtAbout) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtCreateProfile) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetch) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtFetchOptions) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstall) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallBugList) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtMain.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtMain) not found
file apt_offline_gui/Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py (for module apt_offline_gui.Ui_AptOfflineQtSaveZip) not found
running build_scripts
running install_lib
creating /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
copying build/lib/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
copying build/lib/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineDebianBtsLib.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
copying build/lib/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineLib.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
copying build/lib/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineMagicLib.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
copying build/lib/apt_offline_core/__init__.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core
creating /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtAbout.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtCommon.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtFetch.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstall.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtMain.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/QtProgressBar.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/UiDataStructs.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
copying build/lib/apt_offline_gui/__init__.py -> /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineCoreLib.py to AptOfflineCoreLib.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineDebianBtsLib.py to AptOfflineDebianBtsLib.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineLib.py to AptOfflineLib.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineMagicLib.py to AptOfflineMagicLib.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_core/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtAbout.py to AptOfflineQtAbout.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtCommon.py to AptOfflineQtCommon.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.py to AptOfflineQtCreateProfile.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtFetch.py to AptOfflineQtFetch.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.py to AptOfflineQtFetchOptions.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstall.py to AptOfflineQtInstall.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.py to AptOfflineQtInstallBugList.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.py to AptOfflineQtInstallChangelog.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtMain.py to AptOfflineQtMain.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/AptOfflineQtSaveZip.py to AptOfflineQtSaveZip.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/QtProgressBar.py to QtProgressBar.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/UiDataStructs.py to UiDataStructs.cpython-38.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline_gui/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-38.pyc
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-3.8/apt-offline -> /usr/bin
copying build/scripts-3.8/apt-offline-gui -> /usr/bin
changing mode of /usr/bin/apt-offline to 755
changing mode of /usr/bin/apt-offline-gui to 755
changing mode of /usr/bin/apt-offline-gui-pkexec to 755
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apt_offline-1.8.5-py3.8.egg-info
```